# Is Project/Product Management a good choice when switching career from business (14+ years in Marketing & Sales) to IT?

Tags: management, united-states, career-development, project-management, career-switch

I have a bachelor degree in Linguistics, however for the last 14+ years I've been building my career in Marketing & Sales (worked for 1 IT company and 4 non-IT companies).
IT technologies are so deeply integrated in business processes today, that I'm confident my professional profile needs an "upgrade" to improve its competitiveness on the market. I'm 40 now, so makes sense to act fast.
My plan is to obtain graduate (Master's) degree in IT, so that I can switch afterwards from Marketing & Sales to the role in which:

- my previous experience will serve as a valuable asset (there's no point in scoring out 14 years of achievements)
- Master's in IT will be a "layer", which adds new knowledge and skills (and rises the overall ranking of my professional profile)

**Important note #1:** my recent roles in Marketing & Sales have been on the "upper-mid/senior" level. This means I am responsible for a long-term strategy, P&L management, team management and business process efficiency. **[/EndOfNote]** 
While MBA at a first glance seems to be a better choice with my background, it's on purpose that I decided to go for Master's. Firstly, every other has MBA degree today, secondly - only Top-10 schools add a widely-recognized value, finally - my long-term practical work experience to the certain extent overlaps with the knowledge gained from MBA program.
Last but not least - MBA is (mostly) a "helicopter view" education, while Master's as a part of my strategy, is supposed to serve as a source of focused, concentrated knowledge in a specific area.

With all the above-said considered I assume that IT Project/Product Management should be a good choice in my case. It's in demand (and due to its nature shall always be an integral part of IT business as such), it's well paid and it's aligned with my former professional experience.
Based on my current knowledge of IT Project/Product Management role, one of the career growth paths may look like this: 
**Computer Systems Analyst** -> **Project Manager** -> **Product Manager** -> **IT Manager** -> **CTO/CIO**

For simplicity's sake the scheme reflects only vertical career growth and obvious "Junior -> Senior" moves are omitted.
**Important note #2:** my Marketing & Sales role has always supposed fulfillment of tasks typical for *both* - Project Manager and Product Manager. Same as a Project Manager I organized cross-team collaboration (production, logistics, marketing, etc.) to complete certain action on time and on budget (e.g. to expand our sales to the new country, to start production of a new product).

While same as a Product Manager I was responsible for P&L and business development strategy, alignment of the product with customer's needs, go-to-market strategy, etc. **[/EndOfNote]**

**Finally here are my QUESTIONS:**

- do you think Project/Product Management is the right choice in IT with my background? Any other roles in IT as an alternative?
- Computer Systems Analyst is a tactical role, so do you agree that Project/Product Manager will be a better start point in my case?
- which graduate (Master's) education will deliver more "added value" in **my** case? Should my Master's be in Project Management, assuming I need to dive deeper into tech stuff, as I've already gained enough of "strategic" experience? Or is it rather vice versa - I take Master's in Product Management, assuming **this** is the destination role, so I need appropriate education in **this** area to be competitive, while I can gain tech knowledge (in the amount Product Manager needs it!) through practice or additional courses/certification? Is it common for a Master's program to cover both (Project/Product) roles in a **quality** way (not "MBA-style", "helicopter view")?
- would you recommend some specialization within the bounds of those 2 professions which will likely to increase the attractiveness of my profile? I mean not only additional certification (PMP, Prince2, etc.), but possibly focus on specific task (e.g. "Data Security in IT Project Management") or industry (e.g. "IT Product Management in Logistics").

Thank you so much for your help and valuable input!

Comment: I'm not sure about your end goal here. Do you just want the title? Be paid more? Wouldn't it be simpler to reach out for organisation that are looking for what you want to do and ask them what you would need to get this position and what you may be missing?  Where I'm from Master's need the proper education to be accepted, and in some fringe case experience, for anything other than project management. What are you ready to get yourself into and under what conditions?( IE full time student for how long, do a bachelor or more course beforehand,etc)

Comment: We don't do career advice here, but I'll give you this for free: you need to have a much better understanding of IT careers before you go down this route. Project manager, product manager and "IT manager" are much more three separate parallel tracks than a hierarchy.

Comment: Spent too long in sales selling pie in the sky, you want to get into a new industry at a senior level, that doesn't happen. Most of your experience is irrelevant compared to your competitors who will have much more industry focused experience. It could be accomplished through your personal network perhaps... I've seen stranger things happen

Comment: @Alrl Thank you for the input. What I want (if shortly) is to switch the *product* I'm working with. After all Product Manager in IT is a purely Marketing role on strategic level - same what i've been doing all these years, so entering the market which is emerging (compared to classy merchandise) and has a huge growth potential is pretty logical. And yes they pay more there, exactly because of growth - we all work for money, don't we?

Comment: You should probably re-read the [Code of Conduct](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/conduct) at this stage.

Comment: Yes, sounds like pie in the sky.... no offence, sales and marketing is a hugely different field with it's own mindset

Comment: "Product Manager in IT is a purely Marketing role on strategic level".  I suggest you do more research into what a Product Manager does, as that's very much _not it_.

Comment: @Shakalakah - one thing I can highly recommend before you attempt to transition into a tech role is to drop the attitude.  A key part of being an effective product manager is collaboration with your technical team and building trust - something you won't manage if, when asking for advice, you feel the need to be condescending to people who have actually been working in that industry - in some cases - for decades

Comment: I guess if everyone will be thrilled to get a PM with a lot of titles and no actual experience in IT to come tell them what to do... not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are multiple types of “IT” industry, and some may be a better fit for your skill set. Just some examples from my own experience:

1. Pure software development company (or development function in a very large enterprise). In this kind of company Product Management may be a good route for you: a lot of the job requirements are similar to what you’ve done, things like understanding customer needs, business strategy, business cases, team leadership, etc. (N.B. Product Management is quite different to Project Management, and I don’t see much synergy between your skills and Project Manager skills). More significantly those businesses have sales and marketing functions as well, and the lines are normally very blurry between verticals because of the need for everyone to understand the software; why not consider joining a company like that in a mid/senior sales or marketing role, and then either skill-up through your internal contacts or even move sideways in the same company?
2. IT function in any company. I don’t see much similarity between your experience and any roles I’m familiar with in those organisations.
3. IT consultancy. If you enjoy travel, and can work well directly with customers, then these companies offer high salaries and a quick way to get very varied experience. They also have a lot of grey-area roles for business people (as opposed to technical people) blurring the boundaries between sales and Project Management, as quite often somebody involved in selling a deal will also be involved in ensuring the success of the project. Again this is an opportunity to get technical skills while in a business role, because again everyone has to understand whatever technical offering the company is selling.

You’re right that IT roles are usually in high demand... Personally, if I were in your shoes, I would look to apply for some of the more business-focused roles directly rather than trying to step down and then up again, or going through education again. I think a lot of the techies on here may hate me for saying it, because we all find it frustrating working with people in business roles who don’t know the first thing about technology, but the roles are there and in a year or two you’ll have skilled up if you’re willing to put in the effort.

Answer (score 0):

No. Moving to IT from buisness is quite opposite of good career choice. By late 20s most techies strive to "retire" into management. You are basically trying to downgrade your career. It is a crazy and risky move that i wouldn't dare to make now that i dived into my 30s let alone in 40s.
Then there comes ugly stuff like ageism, it will be hard to find tech job in 40s. Doing leaps of faith like this is unnecesary complication at your age OP.

Comment: Thank you Terry for what is really called an **answer**, appreciate that. I understand "techies" moving to management - this is perfectly in line with my understanding of career growth. However, I'm not going to move to "techies", my plan is to **stay** in management, but to change the market/product itself. After a possible *temporary* downgrade (not professional one, but that from a "tactical -> strategic vertical" perspective) I am going to return to the management level, i.e. Product Manager -> Chief Product Officer. If you think it **still** makes no sense, will be great to know - why.